# Return a table of basic physical objects?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

How can I return a table of basic physical objects, e.g., Ball (Q18545), Arrow (Q45922), in Wikidata using SPARQL?

I'm not able to directly return objects with the property Physical Object (Q223557) because it has way too many records. But its subtypes, e.g., Toy (Q11422) or Projectile (Q49393), are too narrow for me. I've tried the following to get my broad query working:

- removing the label service
- using `LIMIT` for a moderate number of records
- filtering out records with very few `sitelinks`
- limiting the objects to those with ids from BNCF Thesaurus ID, BabelNet ID, etc.

Nothing has worked for me. I suspect this is straightforward for anyone who's had more than a few days with Wikidata. Please help.

I shared my wrecked query below.

```
SELECT ?obj #?objLabel 
WHERE {
  {
    SELECT ?obj WHERE {
        ?obj wdt:P508 ?bncfid;
             wdt:P2581 ?bnid;
             wdt:P227 ?gndid;
             wdt:P8814 ?wsid;
             wdt:P18 ?image;
             wikibase:sitelinks ?sitelinks;
             wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q223557.
        #FILTER(?sitelinks > 5).
        #FILTER(LANG(?objLabel)="en").
        #SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". 
        #                       ?obj rdfs:label ?objLabel}
    }
    LIMIT 1000
  }
  #?obj rdfs:label ?objLabel
  #FILTER(LANG(?objLabel)="en").
}
```

(Run by clicking [here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fobj%20%23%3FobjLabel%20%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20SELECT%20%3Fobj%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fobj%20wdt%3AP508%20%3Fbncfid%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP2581%20%3Fbnid%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP227%20%3Fgndid%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP8814%20%3Fwsid%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP18%20%3Fimage%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wikibase%3Asitelinks%20%3Fsitelinks%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2A%20wd%3AQ223557.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23FILTER%28%3Fsitelinks%20%3E%205%29.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23FILTER%28LANG%28%3FobjLabel%29%3D%22en%22%29.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fobj%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FobjLabel%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20LIMIT%201000%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%23%3Fobj%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FobjLabel%0A%20%20%23FILTER%28LANG%28%3FobjLabel%29%3D%22en%22%29.%0A%7D))

Comment: either load Wikidata into your own triple store if the public service is too slow or try e.g. the Qlever instance: https://qlever.cs.uni-freiburg.de/wikidata/p7tZ1W

Comment: @UninformedUser Do you recommend a resource for walking someone through the process of loading Wikidata into their own triple store? I found [Your own Wikidata Query Service, with no limits](https://addshore.com/2019/10/your-own-wikidata-query-service-with-no-limits/), which is very comprehensive. Total time to complete task estimated as 5.5 days. So, this definitely isn't a trivial undertaking!

Comment: the loading itself is in fact "trivial", any triple store of your choice usually provides a guide how to setup the store itself and load any RDF data - and for Wikidata there is an RDF dump downloadable. And yes, it takes "some" time, Wikidata is quite huge. For example, you could setup open source software like, among others, Apache Jena Fuseki (TDB as backend), Virtuoso, Blazegraph or e.g. Qlever. Most of them nowadays also provide a Docker container which makes the setup even easier. In the meantime you could download Wikidata which also takes time. Then load it

Comment: Or you just use the public Qlever as I linked to. The query works there and returns the result in a few seconds. Indeed, you have to remove those magic functions from the Blazegraph triple store like `wikibase:` stuff. But good old SPARQL works

Comment: For anyone who stumbles on this, I found [here](https://ad-wiki.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/research/HowTos/WikidataCheatSheet#Ranking_entities) that you can replace the `sitelinks` line with `^schema:about/wikibase:sitelinks ?sitelinks .`, along with `PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>` and `sitelinks` works on Qlever.